# Socket.IOControl method is not supported on Linux platform

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I have one .Net Core 3.1 console application in which Socket.IOControl method used.
When running at linux server(RedHat),it is getting error at runtime.
Please find the below code,

**Code:**

```
Socket m_Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

m_Socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(m_OriginAddressIP, m_iPort));
m_Socket.IOControl((IOControlCode)SIO_UDP_CONNRESET, new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 }, null);
```

Error:

> **"Socket.IOControl handles Windows specific control codes and not supported on linux platform"**

How to solve this error in linux?

Comment: Could it be that linux UDP sockets don't react to ICMP PORT_UNREACHABLE responses by default? In that case the IOControl can be skipped on linux.